# 'Enter key' wont submit form in Firefox, but will in Chrome, why?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form, very basic, and when I hit enter key nothing happens in firefox, but in google chrome it submits. Haven't tried other browsers yet...

Nothing happens at all when hitting enter in firefox.

When clicking the submit button it works fine in both browsers.

The form is inside a DIV, and the form has javascript too, here is the form simplified:

```
<form id="nav_form_main" name="nav_form_main" action="bincgi/sql_query.php" target="iframe001" method="get" onSubmit="reset_pager();">

<input type="button" name="nav_submit" id="nav_submit" value="Search" onClick="reset_and_subm();" style="width: 58px; font-size: 13px;">

//some other elements...

</form>
```

and here is the js:

```
function reset_pager(){
    byId("p").value = 0;
}
function reset_and_subm(){
    byId("p").value = 0;
    document.forms["nav_form_main"].submit();   
}
```

The reset_pager function is not called at all... which is strange because it is an "onsubmit" function. So it is like the form isn't submitted at all.
However, the results in the targeted iframe appear fine, without any problem.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: All I can think of is that there is something wrong inside the form, I have alot of elements... What do you think?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Enter* for submit is only triggered if `<input type="submit>` exists on the form. You can add a hidden one for this purpose, but keep in mind that it will submit the form and bypass the `onclick` event you're looking to capture. You'll need to patch into the `onsubmit` action of the form to run your function.

Comment: Note that if you try to hide the `<input type="submit">` with something like a `display:none;`, Chrome will prevent the Enter key from submitting.  Instead, you have to keep it "displayed", but position it into oblivion with something like this: `<input type="submit" style="position: absolute; left: -10000px;top: -10000px;"/>`

Comment: This is a really old post but... it should be noted that if you define the name attribute `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>`  on the submit input, the form will not submit in chrome.  No clue why. But I spent an hour debugging so I thought I would share.

Comment: This was never a thing. Now I suddenly stumbled on it and really wonder why, when and where this behavior come from.

Answer (score 3):

As Diodeus mentioned, you need an `<input type="submit">` tag in your form if you want to use the *ENTER* key to submit the form.

The reason that your `reset_pager` function is not firing on the `onsubmit` event is because the `onsubmit` event is never fired. Though it's somewhat counter-intuitive, using the `submit()` method on a form (as you're doing in your `reset_and_subm` function) will not cause the `onsubmit` event to fire.

You have a couple options:

1. You can add an `<input type="submit">` to your form and put all your logic in an `onsubmit` callback function.
2. Watch all `keypress` events on the form. If the *ENTER* key is pressed or the button is clicked, then call a function that does all the stuff you want to happen before submitting the form and then call `submit()` on the form.